# fullcalendar. If I hide month view and navigate to previous month, how could I rerender events to their perfect place

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I have another self-defined agenda view. If the user clicks on button agenda, then, original view will be hidden. When the user navigate month, I have ajax call to get event data. On normal view, events are showing perfect. After I hide the normal view and use my agenda view, when the user wants to go back to normal month view, all event are squeezed to left side. 
So, my question is How do I have event render properly when I call $(element).show() and where is right place to do it?

Answer (score 0):

probably call the `rerenderEvents` method
http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/rerenderEvents/

Answer (score 0):

I know it's over a year old, but I'll answer this because I came up with the same issue.

You need to set the fc-view-month, agendaWeek and agendaDays to visibility - hidden with CSS and also height to 1px.

```
$('.fc-view-month').height('1px').css('visibility', 'hidden');
```

Then show your agenda List view.

I tried quite a few of the methods that fullcalendar has and although it drew the events, they were shifted to the left.  Probably due to not being able to find where the calendar dates are as the view is hidden by hide().  Setting the views to visibility - hidden means it can still see the calendar date.

Hope this is helpful to someone :)